# Accessing css variable in JS file

Tags: css, angular

I am having a `CSS` file which has some variable define

```
 @red: red-color
 @yello: yellow-color
 ....
```

I can use this variable in `CSS` file, But I want to know how can I access them in my `JS` file.

Comment: What css preprocessor are you using?

Comment: you can't. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using native CSS variables and not some preprocessor, take a look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). At the bottom there's a section called **Values in JavaScript** which describes how to access native CSS vars in JS code.

```
getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--my-var");
```

However if you are using a CSS preprocessor, it is not possible to retrieve the variables via JS since they're already processed in the build process.

Comment: I guess you missed a link

Comment: Did you forget to add link? Also, link only answer is not a good way to answer any question. Do provide the code snippet and description of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not CSS variables, but LESS variables (as they start with "@")

Those get compiled into simple, static property declarations, so no way to change them at runtime (other than addressing every property).

IF you use proper CSS variables (aka CSS Custom Properties) you can easily access them with javascript at runtime and chage it with the style.setProperty method.

But they are not widely (enough) supported, so make sure to include a fallabck.