# React and SCSS export a variable from scss to react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

i am trying to export a color from my .scss file to my React.

colors.scss

```
:root {
  --color2: #606060;
}

$color: #88b5dd;
$color2: var(--color2);

.export {
 color: $color
 color2: $color2
}
```

and reading it in my React:

App.js

```
import {Colors} from './colors.scss'
console.log(Colors.color)
console.log(Colors.color2)
```

and in the console.log i can see:

```
#88b5dd
var(--color2)
```

color2 is not a color, the var(--color2) doesn't get interpolated when im using export
anyone knows how to fix this issue ? how can i get the color defined in :root?
thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing css variable in JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153360/accessing-css-variable-in-js-file)

Comment: im not sure how to use getPropertyValue, because i need to pass an element. which element do i pass ?

Comment: You can use `document.documentElement`

Comment: @GalShtengel define `:root` variables on the top of the file and styles.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [solution in this website](https://medium.com/@christian.tonye_16869/scss-variables-in-react-typescript-components-de19d7f96245). Here's the gist, in case the post gets deleted.

Create a modular scss file containing your scss variables, or import them from the original files using `@use`.

```scss
// _globalVars.scss

$mobile-breakpoint: 900px;
```

```scss
// exporterFile.module.scss

@use './globalVars'

$new-variable: red;

:export {
  mobileBreakpoint: globals.$mobile-breakpoint;
  newVariable: $new-variable;
}
```

As you can see above, the required variables were exported using the `:export{}` syntax. These can then be imported into a JS or TS file.

```
import myScssVars from 'exporterFile.module.scss'

console.log(myScssVars); // { mobileBreakpoint: '900px', newVariable: 'red' }
```

Unfortunately these are imported as a readonly key value string pair.
[image: VSCode type annotation screenshot].

If anyone finds out how to get inferred types in this, consider answering [my question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275803/how-to-infer-types-from-modular-scss-exports)!

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
found this library `react-css-vars`
and refactor this code to use it with React