# How to infer types from modular scss exports?

Tags: typescript, sass, scss-mixins, css-variables, inferred-type

I have found a way to import scss variables into ts and js using [this article](https://medium.com/@christian.tonye_16869/scss-variables-in-react-typescript-components-de19d7f96245)

**Basically the approach is:**
Create a modular scss file containing your scss variables, or import them from the original files using `@use`.

```scss
// _globalVars.scss

$mobile-breakpoint: 900px;
```

```scss
// exporterFile.module.scss

@use './globalVars'

$new-variable: red;

:export {
  mobileBreakpoint: globals.$mobile-breakpoint;
  newVariable: $new-variable;
}
```

As you can see above, the required variables were exported using the `:export{}` syntax. These can then be imported into a JS or TS file.

```
import myScssVars from 'exporterFile.module.scss'

console.log(myScssVars); // { mobileBreakpoint: '900px', newVariable: 'red' }
```

Unfortunately these are imported as a readonly key value string pair.
[image: VSCode type annotation screenshot].

How do I infer the actual types for the variables set in scss?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve a similar behavior with the following lib: [typed-scss-modules](https://github.com/skovy/typed-scss-modules)

So you need to do the following:

- Install as a devDependency: `yarn add -D typed-scss-modules`
- Go to you *package.json* and add a new script `generate-scss-types: yarn typed-scss-modules src/yourPath/toMainScssFiles`
- Run the new script: `yarn generate-scss-types`

> You should add a path to your main scss folder to prevent `.d.ts` files on very `.scss` file that you have on the project.

After doing it, you will have something like this:

```
/scss/
   --/ _color.variables.module.scss
   --/ _color.variables.module.scss.d.ts
```

Where `_color.variables.module.scss` had:

```
// primary
$primary: #2d64f1;
$primary-light: #7491ff;
$primary-dark: #003bbd;

/*
 * Color Map (used for color classes and direct usage in components)
 */
$colors: (
  'primary': $primary,
  'primaryLight': $primary-light,
  'primaryDark': $primary-dark,
);

:export {
  @each $name, $value in $colors {
    #{unquote($name)}: $value;
  }
}
```

And `_color.variables.module.scss.d.ts` will have:

```
export const primary: string
export const primaryDark: string
export const primaryLight: string
```

So then each time that you import your colors, you will have the IDE autocomplete and also the TS options like `keyOf` or `typeOf`

[image]

Side note:

> This same approach will work for every other `.scss` file that you have, I just show you the colors, but the same will happen if you have "breakpoints" or "fonts"

Comment: Nice! It would be nice if this was possible without the extra library. Maybe there's some way to natively do what this library does.